# Linq to Sql Classes missing from within a script task in visual studio 2013 in an SSIS package

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I'm trying to migrate an existing Visual Studio C# project to run in a script task in an SSIS package.

The current C# console application uses "Linq to Sql Classes" to generate a dbml file and the necessary classes.

But when I go to edit the script task in the SSIS PACKAGE I'm not able to find the LINQ TO SQL CLASSES. I right click on the project and select "add -> new item" and look for the "Linq to Sql Classes" item to add the dbml file to my project but it's not there?

Confusing because if I do the exact same thing in Visual Studio 2013 in a console application, I'm able to add the "Linq to Sql Classes".   Does anyone have any ideas? I realize I could use Entity Framework but that would take a considerable amount of time to re-write everything. Also I've thought about just executing the console application's compiled executable from within the SSIS package but our database team will not allow packages to run executables.

Also I'm targeting the .net framework 4.0 for both the Visual Studio 2013 console applications and from within the Visual Studio 2013 editor in the SSIS Package Script Task.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question because I have(had) this exact same problem. We had an existed DataContext file which had been mapped to a database. I had updated the database which SSIS but my changes werent being reflected in the Script task. I created a seperate project and created a linq-to-sql file and connected it to the same database as my Script task. Then added all the existing tables and the new one too. which generated a new Datacontext file. I then copied the code back into the original Datacontext file within the script task.

Hope this helps you and future programmers